# Firebase OnTokenRefresh() never called?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging. The message onTokenRefresh is not called in my Android App. It worked some time before but now I do not get a new token.

My Code:

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Log.e("Token refresh","Method called");
}
}
```

I initiate the method call by `String fcm_token =  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`
The String is null, perhaps because FCM works asynchronously.

My Manifest:

```
<service
  android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong? I also tried `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();` before. It causes a timeout.

Comment: Are your dependencies up-to-date?
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4

Comment: Please add as an answer. It was the solution. I used firebase 11.0.1 and that did not work.

Comment: So, change firebase version did the trick?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why. That is a bad development by Google if older versions do not still work.

Comment: I am glad that you have your answer. I just wonder if that really works, because firebase has been released for a long time. And refreshToken worked in the first days...

Comment: Maybe change version force them to recompile and it work for first time, then it's not. Sorry @DeividasStrioga, I respect your answer. I just have a little bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your dependencies to com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4 com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4.